# No command shell echo on WES2009 startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, embedded, startup

I have built WES2009 image with the CMD command shell, and everything works fine. The CMD command line shows after the boot.

I start automatically the batch file through the registry "Run" section. The batch file executes, but it does not show any sign of it's execution on the screen. The screen just comes with the CMD prompt. How can I make all the echoes and commands to show on the screen as a part.

Comment: Does your script have any output if you run it manually?  Do you want the commands themselves to be visible?  If so, did you remove or remark out `@echo off` from the top of your script?

Comment: When I run it manually it works as expected (e.g. shows echo, interacts properly). It appears that the script on the startup runs in a different command shell.

Comment: Was it within the HKLM hive or in HKCU that you added a reference to the batch script?  Does it make any difference to remove the registry entry and instead place the bat script within "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"?

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: It is in HKLM. I tried to follow your advice. There is no %APPDATA% on the system. Instead, there is %USERPROFILE\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp. However, when I put the batch file there it does not execute at all.

Comment: What actually happens is that WES2009 launches two command windows, whereby the one that I launch is not visible (I proven this by giving mine a duration of 1 minute using ping command). The problem is essentially how to combine the windows or alternatively show the one that I start on the desktop.